# The Torus is compact $T= -1\leq z\leq 1,x^{2}+y^{2}=\left ( 2-\lambda \right )^{2}$ where $\lambda ^{2}= 1-z^{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, 3d

Sorry guys, but i'm stuck on this problem since a week ago, trying to figure out how to proof this Torus is compact by Heine-Borel Theorem, i guess the hardest part of it, is to proof is closed, i tried to make it by succesions, thinking that the closure is equal to the Torus itself, but by the way it's defined i guess it pretty complicated to do that. I been searching on Topology and Analysis books but there's no much useful things, also i can't see the Torus as cartesian Product.
$T = (x, y, z)~\in~\mathbb{R}^{3} -1\leq z\leq 1,~x^{2}+y^{2}=\left ( 2-\lambda  \right )^{2}$ where $\lambda^{2}=1-z^{2}$
Anyone can give an advice or teach me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function
$$f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2, \quad (x, y, z) \mapsto \left(x^2 + y^2 - \left(2-\sqrt{1-\min\{1,|z|\}^2}\right)^2, z\right)$$

is continuous and as $A := \{0\} \times [-1,1]$ is closed, so is $T = f^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: So basically is figure out what happens on the interval {0}×[−1,1] on the Torus?

Comment: Sorry, I don‘t understand your question. $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$ is not on the torus and there is no inverse function.

Comment: My mistake, i did not analyze enough the answer, but still...you take A:={0}×[−1,1] as a result of the restriction on the Z-axis ?

Comment: @AbrahamBerrielRangel, it looks as if you’re missing the point here. Keba has given the full proof, nothing more to do. The inverse image (we called it “counterimage” when I was a boy, and I prefer that still) of a closed set under a continuous map is closed. In your case, the torus is the set of points that go to $\{0\}\times[-1,1]$ under the map that Keba has given the formula for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lubin

Comment: Yeah at first i was kinda confused about the answer cos it was a total different proof of what i was expecting, but since that day i understood the argument and it was because i've forgotten the definiton of a closed set under a continuous map is closed. But Thanks for the Reply really @Lubin

Comment: And also i forget that by Wierstrass Theorem that if is continuous in an interval then that interval is closed

Comment: Weierstrass’s theorem that you just quoted, @AbrahamBerrielRangel, is a rather different, says that the image (not counterimage) of a compact is again compact (and that the only compacts $\subset\Bbb R$ are finite unions of closed bounded sets), but the cruciality here is not the image but the counterimage.